# setsockopt IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE flag return error (linux)

Tags: linux, c

I try to use setsockopt with the flag IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE but i keep getting the wired error from errno Protocol not available this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4/ip_tables.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void) {
int sock;
int ret;
void *data;
size_t size;
struct ipt_replace *repl;

sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);

if (sock == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    return -1;
}

size = sizeof(struct ipt_replace);

 data = malloc(size); Protocol not available

if (data == NULL) {
    perror("malloc");
return -1;
}

memset(data, 0, size);

repl = (struct ipt_replace *) data;

repl->num_counters = 0x1;
repl->size = 0xffffffff;
repl->valid_hooks = 0x1;
repl->num_entries = 0x1;

ret = setsockopt(sock, SOL_IP, IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE, (void *) data, size);

printf("\ndone %d\n", ret);
perror("error: ");



return 0;
}
```

this is the output :

```
sock:3 
data: 
size:92 
done -1
error: : Protocol not available
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking briefly at the kernel code, this would seem to indicate that the IP tables module isn't available (i.e. the kernel wasn't built with it configured, or it can't be found or loaded).

It appears to me that for a socket of the kind you created, the code flow is:

- enter `raw_setsockopt`: `level` != `SOL_RAW` so...
- call `ip_setsockopt`: `level` == `SOL_IP` but option isn't any of the `IP_xxx` options so...
- call `nf_setsockopt`: Search loaded netfilter modules for one that has registered `IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE`.

I think the last must have failed, so you get `ENOPROTOOPT` back (== Protocol not available)